# java out of memory error-heap space

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

I'm developing web application in jsp/servlet,i had an issue with netbeans and Java. My program needs large data process. So I used -Xmx512m to increase the maximum heap size via

> Tools -> Servers -> on the Platform tab there is a VM option below
>   Java Platform.
>   Then it works fine..

Now my issue is i'm building the **WAR** file, directly deployed and run in my another machine Tomcat for demo,
here i'm facing the same issue java out of memory error-heap space
 i also tried with

> environment variable set   CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m

this also didn't help me

how to resolve this issue?, Please point me to the right direction

Comment: Make it -Xmx1024m and try again.

Comment: where in the environment variable?

Comment: Finally i found the solution for the issue see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i found the solution for the issue

in Catalina.bat file 
you can find some text like below

```
set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA%
set MAINCLASS=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
set ACTION=start
set SECURITY_POLICY_FILE=
set DEBUG_OPTS=
set JPDA=
```

under that you need to put the

> set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m

Heap size is larger than your computer's physical memory. For example,

java -Xmx2g BigApp
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

The fix is to make it lower than the physical memory: java -Xmx1g BigApp

Answer (score 11):

Try to set `PermSize`and `MaxPermSize` values and that should be set at tomcat **startup** in `Catalina.bat` and then `stop` and `start` using this script.

```
  set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

http://javahowto.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/6-common-errors-in-setting-java-heap.html

Comment: @Sathish which env are you using ? Window or Unix ?

Comment: in Catalina.bat which line i need to add that

Comment: @duffymo did you see the Catalina.bat file there are many line are there .. thats y i asked

Comment: Where you have `set CATALINA_OPTS=` . you have to update this line.

Comment: @Sathish - yes, but they don't all set CATALINA_OPTS.

Comment: Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine. after that line update im not able to start the tomcat getting this error

Comment: no there is no set CATALINA_OPTS line. there is the line <rem   CATALINA_OPTS   (Optional) Java runtime options used when the "start",>

Comment: which Tomcat version are you using ?

Comment: If you have JAVA_OPTS in that file you can set these here also , they will work

Comment: i will try and let you know @amicngh

Comment: after setting the JAVA_OPTS also the isssue remins the same Exception in thread "http-bio-7070-exec-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 2):

I know I am totally late on this reply but in case it would be helpful to anybody runs into the same situation I think it worth to put a note here. I am referring to tomcat 9 so you might need to check how things mentioned here are relevant to your version:

In %CATALINA_HOME%/bin/catalina.bat, it clearly stated that:

```
rem   WHEN RUNNING TOMCAT AS A WINDOWS SERVICE:
rem   Note that the environment variables that affect the behavior of this
rem   script will have no effect at all on Windows Services. As such, any
rem   local customizations made in a CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.bat script
rem   will also have no effect on Tomcat when launched as a Windows Service.
rem   The configuration that controls Windows Services is stored in the Windows
rem   Registry, and is most conveniently maintained using the "tomcatXw.exe"
rem   maintenance utility, where "X" is the major version of Tomcat you are
rem   running.
```

If you check your %CATALINA_HOME%/bin folder, you could find a file named like "tomcat9w.exe". Double click on it and you could see this screen shot where you can set your Xms and Xmx parameters for it to save into registry for you

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory error can be result of big session-timeout number in Tomcat's web.xml. In that case many web sessions can take many system memory.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you enable heap dump and analyze using IBM support Workbench (which has heap dump analyzers) and understand the problem exactly and make configurations accordingly.